# Adding zeroes at the end of an array based on the length the a Numpy Array Python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, format, append

How would I be able to make a function that adds zeroes at the ending of the numpy array if they are below the `limit`. So the `val` array below will be transformed into the Expected Outputs below.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

val=np.array([1,4,11])

def Adjust(limit):
    #Funtion needed


Adjust(5)
Adjust(2)
Adjust(3)
Adjust(6)
```

Expected Output:

```
[1,4,11,0,0]
[1,4,11]
[1,4,11]
[1,4,11,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def Adjust(arr, limit):
    if len(arr)<limit:
        return np.concatenate([arr, np.zeros(limit-len(arr), dtype = arr.dtype)])
    return arr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val=np.array([1,4,11])

def Adjust(limit):
    return np.concatenate([val, np.zeros(max(0, limit - len(val)))])

def dbg(limit):
    print(Adjust(limit))

dbg(5)
dbg(2)
dbg(3)
dbg(6)
```

- `[0] * n` creates an array of zeroes with len n
- `a1 + a2` concatenates two arrays

Comment: 'val' in your code looks like a list to me. while in OP's question 'val' is an np array. '[0]*n' also looks like a list to me, not an array. '+' may concat lists, but it doesn't work that way for np arrays. try running 'np.arange(3) + np.arange(5)' and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I updated my solution

Comment: i think it would be a little more efficient to check if you need to concatenate or not before calling the concatenate function. inside your call to concat, you call max, which does that and then you call concat anyway. instead of always calling concat, you can avoid performing this unnecessary work by only calling concat if the length of 'val' is under 'limit'.